# How to properly allocate and deallocate box2d objects in cocos2d, iOS

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, memory-management, box2d-iphone

I wonder what is the best way to allocate and deallocate box2d objects (b2World and b2Body) in cocos2d for iOS?

**Allocate**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) b2World * world;
@property (nonatomic, assign) b2Body * body;
```

**Deallocate**

```
-(void)dealloc {
      delete _world;
      _world = nil;
      _body = nil;
```

Can somebody explain why I can not use retain and release for b2World and b2Body and why do we use delete _world in dealloc method? Why do we not delete body objects also? (delete _body doesnt work). When setting pointers to nil: should I use nil or NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder what is the best way to allocate and deallocate box2d objects (b2World and b2Body) in cocos2d for iOS?

using idiomatic, modern C++.

---

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) b2World * world;
@property (nonatomic, assign) b2Body * body;
```

**No**

(unless you implement these yourself properly, which requires much more understanding of the language)

---

```
-(void)dealloc {
      delete _world;
      _world = nil;
      _body = nil;
```

**No**

details below.

---

> Can somebody explain why I can not use retain and release for b2World and b2Body

these are C++ types, not objc types. C++ types may be allocated in many regions (e.g. on the stack, heap, or user defined areas) -- C++ types sre not reference counting aware. if reference counting is what you need, see `std::shared_ptr`. `std::shared_ptr` is rarely ever needed in C++, btw -- if you use several of these, you are likely doing something wrong.

> and why do we use delete _world in dealloc method?

that's how C++ objects are destroyed and freed. specifically, single objects which were created using `new`. and `delete` and you should never have to write `delete` or `delete[]` -- use smart pointers if you have the unusual case where value is unsuitable.

> Why do we not delete body objects also?

you would have to ask the programmer who wrote it -- it's either a leak, or referenced/owned elsewhere.

> When setting pointers to nil: should I use nil or NULL?

`0`

---

Anyways, to get to your subject:

You would generally use this if the objects have default constructors:

```
@interface MONObject : NSObject {
@private
  b2World world;
  b2Body body;
}
@end
```

if you can place those in your `@implementation` block, do so.

and your object would be default constructed before `-init` (unless you set `GCC_OBJC_CALL_CXX_CDTORS` to `NO`, which is a very bad idea).

and your dealloc would look like this:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [super dealloc];
}
```

in this case, you would just not implement `dealloc`. the destructors will be called (provided `GCC_OBJC_CALL_CXX_CDTORS` is enabled).

when you want something more complex than a value (seen above), use a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

finally, be careful how you pass and return C++ types -- they know how to copy themselves. so returning a value (for example) can actually perform very complex copying.